# I run php as apache's module,but could not loading a config file(php.ini)

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

I build PHP source code with those

`'./configure' '--with-gd' '--enable-fpm' '--prefix=/usr/local/php5.6' '--with-curl=/usr/local' '--with-openssl' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local' '--with-mcrypt' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-zip' '--with-zlib' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--with-mysql' '--with-config-file-path=/etc/php5.6'`

and run httpd with libphp5.so file,phpinfo echo

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path |  /etc/php5.6
>
> Loaded Configuration File |  (none)

I have a `php.ini` file in `/ect/php5.6`,however I restart httpd service but nevery loaded a config file.

*My system is CentOS 6.8 and PHP version is 5.6 with Apache2.2*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to set `php.ini` loading path,add one line in `http.conf`:

> PHPIniDir /etc/php5.6

and then it works,so I think whatever config setted when building PHP source is not usefull,only set PHPIniDir can be worked